# Python counting in nested forloops

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops

I'm brand new to python and have an assignment to "Use two nested for loops. Count up in the outer for loop from 0 to 9 and then at every step count back down to zero."

The answer is supposed to be this:

```
i= 0
k= 0
i= 1
k= 1
k= 0
i= 2
k= 2
k= 1
k= 0
i= 3
k= 3
k= 2
k= 1
k= 0
i= 4
k= 4
k= 3
k= 2
k= 1
k= 0
i= 5
k= 5
k= 4
k= 3
k= 2
k= 1
k= 0
i= 6
k= 6
k= 5
k= 4
k= 3
k= 2
k= 1
k= 0
i= 7
k= 7
k= 6
k= 5
k= 4
k= 3
k= 2
k= 1
k= 0
i= 8
k= 8
k= 7
k= 6
k= 5
k= 4
k= 3
k= 2
k= 1
k= 0
i= 9
k= 9
k= 8
k= 7
k= 6
k= 5
k= 4
k= 3
k= 2
k= 1
k= 0
```

So every time the i counts up, k counts down starting from the previous value of i. I believe I understand the general concept of nested forloops, but I'm not sure if my problem lies in identifying the range for k or in printing i and/or k. Here's what I have:

```
for i in range(0,10):
for k in range(i+1):
    print 'i=',i,''
    print 'k=',k,''
```

But it doesn't give me what I need. It seems like k is going up when I run it, probably because of the (i+1) but it's the closest answer I've gotten so far and I've been having a fair amount of trouble. I'm not looking for the answer itself, but if someone could point me in the right direction that would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Check doc for `range`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need your second for loop to go backwards instead of forwards. Right now it is going from 0 to i.

The syntax for this is:

```
for k in range(i, -1, -1):
```

This starts k at i, until k is not -1, applying -1 to it in each iteration.

So your complete program would be:

```
for i in range(0,10):
    print 'i=',i,''
    for k in range(i, -1, -1):
        print 'k=',k,''
```

Output:

```
i= 0
k= 0
i= 1
k= 1
k= 0
i= 2
k= 2
k= 1
k= 0
i= 3
k= 3
k= 2
k= 1
k= 0
i= 4
k= 4
k= 3
k= 2
k= 1
k= 0
i= 5
k= 5
k= 4
k= 3
k= 2
k= 1
k= 0
i= 6
k= 6
k= 5
k= 4
k= 3
k= 2
k= 1
k= 0
i= 7
k= 7
k= 6
k= 5
k= 4
k= 3
k= 2
k= 1
k= 0
i= 8
k= 8
k= 7
k= 6
k= 5
k= 4
k= 3
k= 2
k= 1
k= 0
i= 9
k= 9
k= 8
k= 7
k= 6
k= 5
k= 4
k= 3
k= 2
k= 1
k= 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. That makes more sense and is definitely closer to what I need, but it still isn't exactly the same. In my post, k counts down all the way to zero every time i counts up, so there are multiple k's in a row rather than every other line being k. Does that mean that the range for k is still an issue or am I missing something else that I need to include? Thanks!

Comment: @an223 My answer is meant to be incorporated into your program and replace your second for loop. I have updated the answer to show you a complete program that does what you want.

Comment: @an223 Check now.

Comment: Oh I see! Thanks so much. I understood your comment about the range, but I was confused about why it wasn't working in the order that I wanted. I see now that I should've printed the first one before continuing onto the second. Thanks so much for your help, I really appreciate it